# Elasticsearch - How to add range filter to search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I use [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.0.0a1/) in order to query Elasticsearch in python. 
I want to search documents with `text` field and get all documents that `created` field of them is less than `datetime.now()`. 
I execute the following query but elasticsearch raises error.

```
q = "some word"
es.search(
        index="comment",
        body={
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": f"*{q}*" ,
                    "default_field": "text"
                },
                "range": {"created": {"lt": datetime.now()}}
            },
            "fields": ["id"],
            "size": 10
        },
    )
```

The following is elasticsearch error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')
```

Note: When I comment `"range": {"created": {"lt": datetime.now()}}`, the query will work without error (but datetime filter is not applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine few types of queries like this, use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{"query_string": {"query": f"*{q}*" , "default_field": "text"}}],
      "filter": [{"range": {"created": {"lt": datetime.now()}}}]}
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that full-text `query_string` clause goes into `must` section and gets scored while `range` filter goes to `filter` and ES doesn't calculate scores for these.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks. But, is there any way to have a full-text search, created_time range filter, and score?

Comment: Results will be sorted by score because of the `must`